# Can I use AdaBoost Regressor with Gaussian Process Regressor as base estimator, as my Surrogate Function?

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization, adaboost, probabilistic-programming

I am using a text-extraction model whose hyperparamters I want to optimise. The model takes time(on average 1 hr) for training on the dataset. The algorithm I am using for hyperparameter tuning, is Bayesian Optimization where the Surrogate Function is a Gaussian Process Regressor.

I have data of hyperparameters(X) and corresponding F1 scores(y) for some training instances which I want to fit with a Gaussian Process. The past data of the hyperparameters are mostly human inputs and very biased.

Part 1:

How many points do I must have to fit the Surrogate Function GP with this kind of data? The model takes time to train as it is a text extraction model and collecting even ten records of hyperparameters data vs F1 scores takes huge amount of time. Hence I want to fit the Surrogate with minimum number of training instances.

Part 2:

As I have very less data and that is highly biased, the R2 of the Gaussian process is very less on test set of hyperparameters data. So I am using an Adaboost Regressor on top of the Gaussian process Regressor to fit the data as a surrogate, which improves the R2 score on test data. I am using the Adaboost Regressor as my surrogate model with Gaussian process Regressor as base estimator.

Can I use Probability of Improvement and Expected Improvement as my acquisition function for this process? If not, What other acquisition function can I use for this?

Comment: How many evaluation are you doing? For example, after if we are doing 60 random evaluations and another 60 with what-ever ACQ function (PI/EI/UCB) we are pretty certain that unless we are *really* unlucky we probably have a good solution. I tend to use upper confidence bound (UCB), if I am able to do quite a few random runs initially so I don't worry for my initial points, as it is the most aggressive. Realistically, if BO is where the success or failure of a model lingers at, that model has bigger issues.

Comment: What about the Adaboost Regressor? Can I use the predictions from Adaboost regressor as mean of GP functions and standard deviation predicted from GP and pass them to acqustion function? Ideally we pass the mean and standard deviations of functions predicted from GP to the ACQ function, what if I pass predictions from Adaboost as the mean of the functions there?